# PHP Secure Session's not working

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to figure out how to make a session secure. I have done a lot of research and found what I want, but the secure session is not working correct, and the site does not say how to fix it.

As you look through the code,

Test 1 will fail

but when running it, it needs to pass.

also when you pull $_SESSION variable, there is nothing there in Test1.

What I have noticed is if I put the $_SESSION after encryption it accepts it.

The Function is from the following site: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

```
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = 'test';
 $_SESSION['username'] = 'john';
 $_SESSION['login_string'] = '1234';

 echo 'Session Set<br>';

 sec_session_start();

 // Testing $session pass or fail.

 echo 'test1<br>';

 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
 $_SESSION['username'], 
 $_SESSION['login_string'])){
 echo 'test: Pass'; 
 } else {
 echo 'test: failed';   
 }

 echo '<br>';
 echo 'test2<br>';

 $_SESSION['user_id'] = 'test';
 $_SESSION['username'] = 'john';
 $_SESSION['login_string'] = '1234';

 echo 'Session Set<br>';

 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
 $_SESSION['username'], 
 $_SESSION['login_string'])){
 echo 'test: Pass'; 
 } else {
 echo 'test: failed';   
 }


// Function from following site: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
 function sec_session_start() {
     $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
     /*Sets the session name. 
      *This must come before session_set_cookie_params due to an undocumented bug/feature in PHP. 
      */
     session_name($session_name);

     $secure = true;
     // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
     $httponly = true;
     // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
     if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
         header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
         exit();
     }
     // Gets current cookies params.
     $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
     session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
         $cookieParams["path"], 
         $cookieParams["domain"], 
         $secure,
         $httponly);

     session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
     session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
 }

 // remove all session variables
 session_unset(); 

 // destroy the session 
 session_destroy(); 

 ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to use `$_SESSION` variable before initializing it with `session_start()`

Comment: @Ibu although there's nothing wrong with "using it" without initializing the session, it does wipe the existing contents of $_SESSION.

Comment: Going between webpages with $_SESSION, would it be best to pull out the $_SESSION variable before calling function: sec_session_start()?

Answer (score 0):

Site: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

If you look at this order, I have broken down what is happening on webpage where I am getting my code.

When it gets to protected_page.php, its does not have any $_SESSION info to test.

The last IF statement does not detect $_SESSION variable.

```
 index.php
    db_connect.php > Include_Once
        psl-config.php
    functions.php - sec_session_start()
        session_start();
    process_login.php 

    process_login.php > POST from INDEX.PHP
        db_connect.php > Include_Once
            psl-config.php
        functions.php - sec_session_start()
            session_start(); 
        functions.php - login()
            functions.php - checkbrute()
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $db_password . $user_browser);
    protected_page.php

    protected_page.php > Sending $_SESSION, but $_SESSION does not come through.
            db_connect.php > Include_Once
                psl-config.php
            functions.php - sec_session_start()
                session_start();
            functions.php - login_check()
                 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) { 
                    } else { 
                    Failed
                    }
```